# How to change angular-material radio-button components?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, radio-button

I tried to change the component radio button by the css in my code but it doesn't seem to work.

The normal behavior of this component is to have the button on the left and the label on the right and i want to inverse this order. I want to have the label on the left and the button on extreme right of my parent composant.

The radio composant in my xxx.component.html looks like that:

```
<mat-radio-group
   class="radio-group"
   [(ngModel)]="model">
   <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" *ngFor="let element of list" [value]="element.Id">
        {{element.name}}
   </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

The radio component in chrome looks like that:

```
<mat-radio-group class="mat-radio-group radio-group">
   <mat-radio-button class="mat-radio-button radio-button">
      <label class="mat-radio-label">
         <div class="mat-radio-container">...</div>
         <div class="mat-radio-label-content">...</div>
      </label>
   </mat-radio-button>
   ...
</mat-radio-group>
```

I tried to change the class "mat-radio-container" and put "left:100%!important" but it doesn't worked.
It seems that i can't change the behavior of subclasses, if i change the classes radio-group or radio-button that i created, i can have an influence on the component but i can't change mat-radio-container or mat-radio-label-content per example.

All the test i made was in the xxx.component.scss

Is someone know how i can put this button on the right or how i can change the "subclasses" of this element only in this component ?

edit: I want the label to be aligned on the left of the parent div and button aligned to the right of the parent div, not label on the left and the button closed to the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution with the help of Santa:

HTML:

```
          <mat-radio-group
            class="radio-group"
            [(ngModel)]="xxx">
                <div *ngFor="let element of list">
                    <div class="left-radio-button">
                        {{element.name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-radio-button">
                        <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" [value]="element.id">                
                        </mat-radio-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </mat-radio-group>
```

CSS:

```
.left-radio-button {
  width:95%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right-radio-button {
  width:5%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, "element.name" is just going to be the label for that particular radio button, Can you to put the interpolation

```
{{element.name}}
```

just left to the

```
<mat-radio-button>
```

tags, it seems to work, see the example for your reference,

[Stackblitz example,](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-demo-znnfvb)

Comment: So i'll have to create a div for the ngFor in the mat-radio-button otherwise i will not have access to element.name

Comment: yeah that's true, can you try that!

Comment: Ok, the radio button is now on the right but not on the extreme right of my div maybe i didn't explain it well but i would like to have the label aligned to the left of the div and the button aligned to the right of the div, even if the div is 20000000px width :p
And with this solution i have the button on the right but close to the label :(

Comment: you can have some margins, i added 10px left margin, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-demo-znnfvb can you check if this is fine?

Comment: each of my radio buttons are on a single line.
So this method doesn't align all the button in the right side of the div because all content doesn't have the same size so i can't put margin-left: xxx%